# Requisição HTTP dando erro no Chrome e funciona no Edge e Firefox

Tags: firefox, http-request, angular

Estou com um problema ao fazer uma requisição HTTP com Angular 4, no Edge e Firefox funciona sem problema algum, mas no Chrome dá erro no Post, o Options passa tranquilamente mas o Post não passa, na imagem é mais fácil ver o erro acontecendo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você já tentou limpar o cache do navegador?

Comment: Acabei de limpar o cache, histórico e tudo mais, mas não funcionou.